# Decryption of data

Tags: file-encryption

Apparently, for privacy I have encrypted data on my mobile.  A few pics (family ones).

This I did through ES File manager, was using AppLock previously but encountered a few errors for storage so I decided to encrypt it through ES.

And as it has been a few days since I opened it, I forgot the password.

I've already tried various combinations and all but my attempts gone in vain.  The pics are kinda nostalgic and I don't have a copy elsewhere.

I tried the official site, they were sorry that they do not maintain servers to store the passwords and asked me to keep trying.

Phone specs

> Moto E using ES File manager 3

Comment: If you forgot the password, there's not much anyone can do.  Of course the app don't store anything on any server; your files are stored on *your* device.  When encrypted, it's just on *your* device.

Comment: The entire purpose of encrypting data on your device is to prevent someone without the password from reading it. Some systems show you a recovery key to keep in a secure place; if you don't have that and don't have the password, then anything you could do to read the files is something anyone else with the device could also do, so if it worked there would be no point to the encryption.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the software in question does encryption in a very stupid fashion, the only option you have is to keep guessing at the password. Keep trying.

If you cannot remember the password, take this as a lesson learnt the hard way. The entire point of encryption is to keep someone without the password from getting at the data. If you are afraid that you will forget the password, write it down and keep it in a safe.